# Install Linux mint with Raid

Tags: linux, raid, linux-mint, software-raid, raid-1

My MB supports fake raid (Intel DH67CL motherboard). But I was using the system in 'software raid' as I could not correctly set up fake raid in Debian. Now, I decide to use Linux Mint 12. During the installation, it didn't give me an option to set up raid. Any help on setting up fake raid (if that not possible, software raid) is appreciated.

thanks,
bsr

Answer (score 1):

[jack_'s answer](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=90878#p522997) to a question on the Linux Mint forums is a good step-by-step guide to installing Linux Mint 12 with software RAID.